# Append timestamp for an integer variable

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to append timestamp for an integer variable.

I have a variable intBuildnumber, I want to append timestamp to this variable so whenever I run the scripts the variable will be unique at every run. How to append the dateformat to integer variable in java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Java `Date` class to achieve this:

```
Date date = new Date();
Long luid = (Long) date.getTime();
String uniqueid = luid.toString();
```

Use `uniqueid` generated where ever you want unique id's, you may need to truncate the generated id, to get id with few number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to append your variable with current timestamp. And yeah it has  returntype long.

Answer (score 0):

The most authentic way to fetch timestamp is:

```
long timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
```